# error| TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]

Tags: macros, errors, packages, lingmacros

When trying to use a specific package (ling-macros) I get this error.
Never had it before. It wont compile most of the time.
Rarely it compiles,but then my macro (\lam{P}{s,t} in the example) wont show up in the PDF.

here is my MRE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ling-macros}
\usepackage[
            backend=biber,
            style=apa,
            citestyle=authoryear
           ]{biblatex}

\title{title}
\author{author}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
  \section*{}
   

so this is the end.\\
\lam{P}{s,t}\\





\end{document}
```

Comment: You may have come across some kind of incompatibility between the `ling-macros` and `biblatex` packages.

Comment: @Mico: 
How can I find out the way it interacts with biblatex?
It's my basic setup and it never caused problems till now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens when `logreq.def` is being read, precisely at the first line of code

```
\DeclareLogreqContainer{requests}{(internal | external)*}
```

as shown in your log file

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=20000].
\gb@ifnextchar #1#2#3->
                       \let \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}\def \reserv...
l.8 ...Container{requests}{(internal | external)*}
```

The problem is with `gb4e.sty` that makes `_` and `^` active.

I believe it's better to use `\noautomath` whenever `gb4e` is loaded (in this case by `ling-macros`), but you can solve your issue by loading `ling-macros` *after* `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{ling-macros}

\noautomath

\begin{document}

\lamd{P}{s,t}

\end{document}
```

In `gb4e.sty` we read

```
%  This file allows _ and ^ to be used in ordinary text, hence must be
%  loaded AFTER any file that uses them in their TeX meaning. Hence
%  cgloss(n).sty is loaded early in this file.  This feature is known to
%  cause some problems with other packages, but is maintained for backward
%  compatibility. If you have problems, you can try disabling it by
%  placing the command \noautomath immediately after loading the gb4e package.
%  [Added 2009/12/28]
```

Comment: switching the order was sufficient indeed.
I will keep in mind the \noautomath part.

Thank you, all you wizards!